# How can I draw a string array in Java which changes contents on each loop?

Tags: java

I want to print a quiz to my GUI using my draw method which changes depending on how many times it is looped through, but the way I'm doing it does not print the String[] fruit to the screen. I assume because its not registering the loop I'm trying to make with the time value(?) but I can't figure out why.

```
public class Fruit {

    private String[] fruit = {};

    public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
        int time = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < fruit.length; i++) {
            g.drawString(fruit[i], 100, 100);
        }

        if(time == 0){
            String[] fruit = {
                "Apples",
                "Pears"
            };
        }
        else if(time == 1){
            String[] fruit = {
                "Bananas",
                "Kiwi"
            };
        }
        time++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's at least two things wrong with that code.

1. You redeclare the name 'fruit' in two different local scopes, neither of which has anything to do with the member variable named 'fruit'. The member 'fruit' will never change from the empty array it was initialized to. Possibly you just mean 'fruit = ...' rather than 'String[] fruit = ...'.
2. You set local variable 'time = 0' at the top of the draw() method, and there's nothing to change it.  Therefore at the point you test whether it's 0 or 1, it's always 0.